# Cypress api pagination to find an object

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can I paginate through an API to find an object?
E.g: I have an API "http://localhost:3000/users" that return:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "total": 1645,
            "pages": 83,
            "page": 1,
            "limit": 2
        }
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1643,
            "name": "m k",
            "email": "mk@gmail.com",
            "gender": "male",
            "status": "inactive"
        },
        {
            "id": 1643,
            "name": "m k",
            "email": "mk@gmail.com",
            "gender": "male",
            "status": "inactive"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to find an specific user.
How can I do the request in all pages to guarantee that the user don't exists?

```
    it('Find the new user', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: "GET",
            url: `https://localhost:3000/users?page=${pages}`
        })
        .then((response) => {
            expect(response.body.code).to.equal(200);
            expect(response.body.data.some(user => { return user.email === userToAdd.email })).to.eq(true);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repeat up to, say 10 pages, wrap the request in function that calls itself until found

```js
function getAllUsers(onResponse, page = 0) {

  if (page === 10) throw 'User not found'

  cy.request(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?page=${page}`)
    .then(response => {
      const found = onResponse(response)
      if (found) return
      getAllUsers(onResponse, ++page)           // repeat for next page
    })
}

getAllUsers(response => {
  expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
  const users = response.body.data;
  return users.some(user => { return user.email === userToAdd.email })
})
```

---

You may have to modify this depending on what happens after all pages have been read and the user has not been found

Say there are 5 pages of users, if `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?page=6` returns

- status !== 200
- response.body === undefined or response.body.data === undefined

```js
getAllUsers(response => {
  const statusOk = response.status === 200;
  const users = response?.body?.data;         // optional chaining
  return statusOk && users && 
    users.some(user => { return user.email === userToAdd.email })
})
```

This will return false for those edge condition, and eventually the test will fail at page 10.